# WPF application lost touch capabilities

Tags: wpf, xaml, touch, expression-blend-4

I'm developing a WPF application with VB2010 and expression blend4.
This application is mainly intended to be used through touch user input.
I don't know when and why but all UI_ELEMENTs have lost default touch responsiveness, for example the button click event doesn't rise anymore the click event when touched, the Slider element doesn't slide, and so on.
I'm using framework 4.0

I post the xaml header:

```
<Window
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"     xmlns:my1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"  xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"  xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects" xmlns:DataStore="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Expression.Blend.DataStore.DataStore" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/controls" xmlns:Microsoft_Samples_Kinect_WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers" xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"  mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="MainWindow"
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: did you override any touchEvent ?

Comment: For example?
I've never directly used handles to UIElement's touch event.

Comment: Example: OnPreviewTouchDown

Comment: But I've lost the link between xaml main file and vb main file code-behind.
Now I've restored it in VS but not in blend. If I try to add an event handler in blend it says that the code-behind file isn't indicated. I don't know how to indicate the name of the file to blend.